# Why is $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ defined the way it is?

Tags: vector-bundles

I've been thinking about Grassmannians recently. Think of $\mathbb{R}^k$ as a $k$-dimensional vector space. Let $\text{Gr}_n(\mathbb{R}^k)$ denote the Grassmannian of all $n$-dimensional vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^k.$ (This is a compact, Hausdorf topological manifold of dimension $n(k-n)$.) Let

$ \Gamma^n(\mathbb{R}^k) := \{ (X,v) : X \in \text{Gr}_n(\mathbb{R}^k) \text{ and } v \in X \} . $

There's a standard idea of a vector bundle $\pi : \Gamma^n(\mathbb{R}^k) \twoheadrightarrow \text{Gr}_n(\mathbb{R}^k)$ given by $\pi(X,v) := X.$ This bundle has the nice property that lots of other bundles can be realised as sub-bundles of it. There is a more general definition, where we use $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ in place of $\mathbb{R}^k$. My question is about why we define $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ the way we do.

We define $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ as the set of infinite sequences $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$ where each $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and only finitely many of the $x_i$ are non-zero. We identify $\mathbb{R}^k$ with the sequences of the form $(x_1,\ldots,x_k,0,0,\ldots),$ and then topologize $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ as the direct limit of the sequence $ \mathbb{R}^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \subset \ldots$ Then we get the universal bundle $\pi : \Gamma^n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty}) \twoheadrightarrow \text{Gr}_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty}).$

My question is why do we insist that only finitely many of the $x_i$ are non-zero for each $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots) \in \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$? I understand that it gives a countably infinite dimensional vector space, but that's a result of the definition; it doesn't explain why we define it the way we do. I suspect that it's related to the topology, but I don't really know.

Edit: The context is the OP is reading Milnor and Stasheff.

Comment: It's the direct-sum of countably many copies of $\mathbb R$ as vector spaces.  So it's the appropriate limiting object, and that's the role it's meant to play -- to be something that contains all the finite-dimensional Euclidean spaces, but "no more". 

Comment: Unless you have a more technical question, I think math.stackexchange.com is maybe more appropriate forum. 

Comment: Also it may be good to keep in mind, that this setup gives
$$Gr_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty)= \bigcup Gr_n(\mathbb{R}^k)$$
as a directed union. So it is well approximated by finite dim objects.

Comment: So defined $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is the direct sum (coproduct in LIN). It differs from the product $\otimes \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ (Cartesian product of $\aleph_0$ copies of $\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: I think Donu's comment may be getting at the OP's underlying question. Namely, the space of all ${\mathbb R}$-valued sequences is bigger than we need -- and I suspect that for certain purposes it may be ``too big''.

Comment: @Ryan I think the question is interesting for the beginning graduate student. It raises a lot interesting questions about topology and limits. Even though most of us have thought through these, I see no harm in leaving it open, unless the OP wants to accept the answers in the comments.


Comment: @Donu, thanks for you reply. It seems to me that the right hand side of the equality is (possibly) "bigger" than the left hand side. Let $1^k \in \mathbb{R}^k$ denote the finite, constant sequence, $(1,\ldots,1)$. The limit of $1^k$ as $k$ tends towards infinity does not lie in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$, even though we can identify $1^k$ with $(1,\ldots,1,0,0,\ldots) \in \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ for all $k < \infty.$ I can see that all of the elements of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ can be constructed by the union, but we seem to be able to construct other elements too.

Comment: @Scott: I agree some beginning grad students might be interested in this question, but that's far from making it an appropriate MO question. 


Comment: By the way, to get curly brackets in TeX on this site, you can use \lbrace and \rbrace. 

Comment: @Fly by Night: Concerning your last comment, I don't see the relevance of the limit you mention.  Neither side of Donu Arapura's equation is closed under limits.  And the equation is correct.  For the direction you were worried about, just notice that any element of the RHS is (by definition) an $n$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^k$ for some particular $k$ and therefore an $n$-dimensional subspace of $\mathfrak R^\infty$.

Comment: Scott, I would prefer to see a more focussed question on limits and topology than this on MO.  This question is very open-ended, and doesn't really explain what "Fly by Night"s specific issue is with this definition.  It feels much more the kind of question that a student should ask their advisor first, and then when they know the "standard" stuff, come here and ask something specific.  There could well be a "great answer" to this, but that does not make this a great **MO** question.  Such an answer would be better placed on a wiki.

Comment: "Fly by Night" may be an undergraduate student, a graduate without an advisor yet, or may not have the kind of advisor who wants to talk about the "standard" stuff with their student. My general feeling (as another student of course) is that if you seem to be getting the details but something doesn't "feel" right, just put it away (possibly for a few years :)). The question is borderline, but a lot of borderline questions where the main police are not as comfortable  with the relevant material get answered and remain open. 

Comment: @Daniel, I work as a postdoc at the moment, but vector bundles and topology aren't my area. I've realised that they might be very useful for something I'm doing at the moment. So I've got Milnor and Stasheff's book and I'm trying to teach myself. I don't have a problem understanding the results; it's just the motivation that I'm missing - hence the question. I find it very sad that people are talking about closing a question because they find it easy.

Comment: I agree, but sorry for the false assumptions! Indeed, for the right expert, the majority of questions on the site are pretty easy. Of course, there are limits and the admins do their best but sometimes the outcomes seem a little unfair.

Comment: Fly-by-Night: I voted to close your question because it is very vague and, without any information about what you know already, very hard to answer.  The short answer is that we *don't* insist on using the direct sum.  Sometimes we use a Hilbert space, sometimes something else.  There are lots of models for $BU$ with lots of different features.  Without more background it is impossible to give a good, focussed answer to this question.  It would be better if you asked a more detailed question that is more *mathematical* in nature rather than asking "why?".

Comment: @Andrew: I give specific background, and the definition I gave is very specific. I do insist on using the direct limit. It's the definition given in Milnor and Stasheff's book. If you re-read my OP then you'll see that I give background, an explicit definition, and an explicit question. The question was simple: given the application in mind, why do we insist that only finitely many of the $x_i$ are non-zero?

Comment: p.s. I've been told by someone that there is a very specific reason; but it's so long since he read this kind of stuff that he's forgotten.

Comment: Fly-by-Night: You don't give **your** background!  Hence everyone speculating on what sort of answer you might find acceptable.  You say, "Why do we do this?" when it's not clear that you really understand what the "this" really is.  What context are you working in?  The answer is one thing to a homotopy theorist and another to a differential geometer!  Without knowing more about **you**, it is impossible to know what a good answer to this question would be.

Comment: Incidentally, no-one is trying to "shut you out".  It's simply how the site works.  If you edit your question then it could get reopened.  If you would really like to know how to make your question more focussed to make it more likely to be suitable for this site, I suggest you create an account on meta and ask there for advice.  (Comment threads here are not suitable places for lengthy discussions.)

Comment: Echoing Andrew to some extent: I think the issue is not of "the main police" (can we please stop this kind of metaphor?) but that the question "why do we do this?" is not sufficiently precise. For instance, the OP doesn't seem to ask the more precise question "why don't we do X?" which is more likely to admit a precise answer. The OP says "given the application in mind" but leaves this vague: is there a precise theorem, known to be true with the definition quoted, for which the OP would like an explanation of what goes wrong under "alternative definitions"?

Comment: @Yemon and Andrew: It seems that it was sufficiency precise. As Allen and Donu have answered my question. It's defined the way it is so that it is a CW-complex. Instead of spending time closing questions because you think they are too vague; why not spend more time trying to understand what people are asking? What's so hard in being kind and considerate? Two people (Allen and Donu) were, and they answered my question. While other people used their time and energy to simply make me feel bad. What a waste.

Comment: "Why not spend more time trying to understand what people are asking?" I could turn this round and say "why not spend more time crafting a more localized question that is less open-ended?" Note that **I did not vote to close your question**. The fact that the answer you wanted is "It's a CW complex" is only obvious with hindsight. People work with spaces that are not CW complexes, so how is one meant to have known that this was the desired answer? I reiterate that while your original question may have been clear to you, it was not clear what kind of answer you were expecting or desiring.

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself: my misgivings with your original question were not "I think this question is too basic", but rather that "Without guesswork, I do not know what kind of answer would satisfy the questioner". You did not ask "what goes wrong with Theorem X if we use a different definition", but rather "why is this definition the way it is", which could have been answered flippantly with "because it is the definition that makes some theorems true".

Comment: Belatedly: meta thread http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1119/why-is-this-definition-the-way-it-is/

Answer (score 11):

There's been quite a bit of discussion of this thread in the meta thread.  I'd like to take a stab at answering my interpretation of what the question is getting at.  In a sense there's at least two things going on, and that's part of why I think there's been so much discussion.

To take a step back from Grassmannians, I'd like to mention why one might be interested in $\mathbb R^\infty$.  The Whitney embedding theorem states that every continuous function $f : N \to \mathbb R^k$ can be approximated uniformly by a $C^\infty$-smooth embedding provided $k \geq 2n+1$ where the dimension of $N$ is $n$.  Moreover, any two embeddings $N \to \mathbb R^k$ are isotopic provided $k \geq 2n + 2$.  So if you wanted to, you could replace the class "$n$-manifolds up to diffeomorphism" with "isotopy classes of $n$-dimensional submanifolds of $\mathbb R^k$ provided $k \geq 2n+2$".

A key nice result about the weak topology on $\mathbb R^\infty$ is that any continuous function from a compact space to $\mathbb R^\infty$ has an image in $\mathbb R^k$ for some $k$.  So from the perspective of the Whitney embedding theorem above, "$n$-dimensional manifolds up to diffeomorphism" is precisely "$n$-dimensional submanifolds of $\mathbb R^\infty$ up to isotopy".  The key thing here is the ambient space is now independent of the dimension of the manifold you're talking about.  This is pretty much exactly what's going on with the Grassmannians.

Given a vector bundle $p : E \to B$ over a finite-dimensional space $B$ (say a manifold or a CW-complex), there exists a classifying map for the bundle, meaning $p$ is isomorphic to the pull-back of the tautological bundle over $G_{n,k} \equiv G_k(\mathbb R^n)$.  $n$ is just some sufficiently large integer.   Although people don't state it this way, this theorem is basically *the Whitney embedding theorem* but for vector bundles.  Because it's saying that up to isomorphism, $E$ is a collection of pairs $(b,v)$ where $b \in B$ and $v \in \chi^{-1}(h(b))$, where $\chi : E_{n,k} \to G_{n,k}$ is the tautological bundle over $G_{n,k}$.  $h : B \to G_{n,k}$ the classifying map. In a sense we've "embedded" the vector bundle in Euclidean space, well, we've made the *fibers* as subspaces of Euclidean space.

But again, you have the "for some $n$ sufficiently large" thing.  And like with manifolds $n$ has an upper bound in terms of the dimension of $B$ (if $B$ is finite dimensional).  Since it's sometimes awkward to carry-around these "for sufficiently large $n$" statements, you take the limit space $G_{\infty,k}$ and now your statement is far more clean, because *any* $k$-dimensional vector bundle over *any* space $B$ is the pull back of some map $B \to G_{\infty,k}$.  The point is that $G_{\infty,k}$ is a *universal* space -- independent of $B$ or the vector bundle over $B$.  The weak topology is exactly what allows us to ensure this happens.

Answer (score 10):

This way it's a CW-complex, so studiable by standard tools of algebraic topology (pretty close to Donu's comment).

For a striking example of how these things can depend on the
definition, look at the infinite unitary groups $U(\infty)$
vs. $U({\mathbb H})$, where the first is defined as $\bigcup U(n)$
and the second as the group of *all* unitary operators on Hilbert space.
Then $U(\infty)$ has very interesting homotopy 
($\pi_n(U(\infty)) = 0$ if $2|n$, $= {\mathbb Z}$ if not),
whereas $U({\mathbb H})$ is contractible.

Comment: I must admit that I'm not happy with the example you chose!  $U(\infty)$ is **not** the unitary group of $\sum_{\infty} \mathbb{R}$.  You can take a Hilbert space $\mathbb{H}$ and form a very nice closed subgroup of $U(\mathbb{H})$ which has the homotopy type of $U(\infty)$.  What's more, this one is a smooth (infinite dimensional) manifold, unlike $U(\infty)$.  There are lots of models for $BU(\infty)$, each with their own advantage, but I think that several of them are CW complexes.  The advantage of this model that springs to mind is that it is fairly easy to show that (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) any map $X \to BU(\infty)$ from a **compact** $X$ factors through some $BU(n)$.

Comment: Thank you very much Allen, that makes sense. And thanks to Donu too; I wasn't saying he was wrong, I was just expressing a confusion. I appreciate both of your efforts. I'm glad I managed to get an answer despite other people's efforts to shut me out.

Comment: Dear Allen: Is there a simple reason why $U(\mathbb{H})$ is contractible?

Comment: @Akhil: That is the content of Kuiper's theorem.

Comment: Akhil: Kuiper's paper is well worth a read on that.  One key step is that you can write a Hilbert space as a countable sum of copies of itself.  Then if you consider a map in to the unitary group from a sphere, you can shift it so that it takes values in just one factor, then do the Mazur-swindle (is that it's name?  I forget) which cancels what happens in that factor by something in the next, then that gets cancelled by something in the third, and so on.  It really is a neat proof.

Comment: @Ulrich, Andrew: Thanks. This sounds pretty interesting. 

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the following is so obvious that no one saw fit to mention it in a comment:

Let $X$ be a paracompact topological space.  With the definition the way it is, homotopy classes of maps from $X$ to the $n$-Grassmannian are in bijection with isoclasses of rank $n$ vector bundles on $X$.  (If you haven't got to them yet, this is thms 5.6 and 5.7).  This is what really gets used in application to Stiefel-Whitney classes.

I don't know what is classified by the other definition of the $n$-Grassmannian you suggest ($n$ dimensional subspaces of the product of infinitely many copies of the reals).  But certainly for your purposes (working through Milnor+Stasheff) this is the point.

The fact that the usual Grassmannian is a direct limit is used in several technical lemmas in chapter 5, but I have never tried pushing the construction you suggest through.

Comment: That result only depends on the _homotopy type_ of the Grassmannian, and all the different possibilities have the same homotopy type, so it doesn't address the actual question as to why Milnor and Stasheff use *this particular* model.

Comment: Andrew, it's not clear to me that the other definition will have the same homotopy type.  Is it clear to you?

Comment: Andrew, I'm not sure our understandings of the question are the same.  I thought the question was, "Why use the direct sum of countably many real lines instead of the direct product?".  Your comment seems to indicate that you think the questioner was asking why Milnor and Stasheff use the particular model they do rather than any other model.  I have to admit, I think the answer to your version of the question is easy: because it's technically convenient.  After all, if your goal is thms 5.6 and 5.7, getting any model, by hook or by crook, is fine, and the one they use is the obvious one.

Comment: SPG: I'm not sure how this question is to be read, which is one of the problems with it as an MO question.  I'm not sure what you get for the direct product, but there are many spaces in between which are perfectly fine.  As to why they all have the same homotopy type, then that's a theorem on infinite dimensional manifolds which identifies their homotopy types with a colimit construction.  But whatever the *model*, the results that you start with only depend on the homotopy type so don't say anything particular about one model versus any other.  (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) I actually think that the last two sentences in your comment are the best answer to this question: they needed **a** model, and this one is the nearest one to hand.

Comment: Andrew,  I thought the question was pretty clear (and don't understand all the fuss): why define the Grassmannian of n-planes using the direct sum instead of direct product?  The cleanest possible answer is: because using direct product doesn't classify vector bundles on paracompact spaces.  Unfortunately, it's not clear to me that this is true, but it might be worth thinking about for a little while for someone who is interested.



Comment: SPG I didn't (and still don't) see anything that implies that we are comparing the direct sum with the direct product.  It seems more "Why the direct sum as opposed to ... err ... anything else?".  There certainly are other things that work just as well.  (I don't know, either, whether the direct product is one of them.)  But that's one of the issues I have with this question: it is possible to read it in too many different ways and each has a subtly different answer.

Comment: From the question: "My question is why do we insist that only finitely many of the xi are non-zero for each (x1,x2,x3,…)∈R∞?"  If we do not insist this, we get the direct product, do we not?  This seems unambiguous to me.

Comment: In fact, that's the only sentence in the OP's question with a question mark after it, so I'm even more puzzled by your assertion that you don't see anything that implies we are comparing the direct sum with the direct product.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously tastes/opinions vary, but *I* think *some* ambiguous, or insufficiently localized, or not publishable-research-y enough, but nevertheless valuable to (a significant demographic of) research mathematicians... In fact, sometimes these questions are exactly the "dumb, non-research" questions that "everyone" (anyway, *many* people) have asked themselves... and not received a cogent answer.

One cliched-but-important (in my opinion) point is the "naive category-theory" explanation of why $\mathbb R^\infty$ is "defined" to be what it is. This does raise the entirely legitimate meta-meta-question of why we "have definitions", and "who is authorized to make them"... to which the easy answer (in my opinion, with some hindsight) is that, not merely must definitions capture the phenomena of important examples (or else the definitions are dumb), but, actually, as it seems to happen very often, re-ordering the "definition...theorem" sequence to "(mapping-)characterization..." rewrites the narrative so that the required/desired property is written in mildly category-theoretic terms, and the technical bit is perhaps proof-of-existence.

That is, a (typically, set-theoretic) "definition" is actually just _one_specific_construction_ of an object whose *important* features (if it exists at all) are completely determined by its interactions with other objects. That is, its characterization is "category theoretic" rather than "set theoretic".

(Yes, this is an advertisement for a certain little bit of category theory, though it is not a *paid* advertisement, insofar as I do not at all advocate *formal* category theory, nor would I advocate allocating one's personal resources to fretting over reconciliation of set theory and category theory... e.g., Grothendieck's "universes" and large cardinals? Fun, but likely not refering directly to one's original issue...)

So, rewriting the question about "why is the definition of $\mathbb R^\infty$ what it is?", we are *required* to ask what *function* this thing should have. Well, it is almost immediate that it should be the _ascending_union_ of the $\mathbb R^n$'s. That is, (upon reflection!) it is a (filtered) colimit (a.k.a. "inductive limit"). That is, it should/must/does have certain diagrammatic/mapping properties... as opposed to goofy set-theoretic constructional details.

Issues about infinite-dimensional Grassmannians... infinite-dimensional simplicial complexes... do share that basic feature, namely, that there is a mapping property (if only ascending-union sorts of (filtered) colimit properties) that are relevant.

Truly, the above viewpoint seems to me to be extraordinarily efficient/effective as explanatory device...

(And, one more time, questions that fail to be "documentable research" sometimes are far more interesting and useful to "us" than more focused ones... Of course, this is not a general rule...)

Answer (score -1):

If we don't insist that all but finitely many entries are non-zero, then we get the (set-theoretic) product of countably many copies of ${\mathbb R}$. If we look at the degree-n Grassmanian of this object, then this is not the object defined in Milnor Stasheff. Hence there exists at least one theorem that is true for the object they define, which is not true for the object we have just defined.

Comment: I very rarely downvote. However, this answer is a role model for an unuseful answer. (Which may make it of some use, after all.)

Comment: Yemon, your answer may be intended rhetorically but is it evidently correct? Could it be that the Grassmannians of $n$-dimensional subspaces of the sum and the product, with their tautological vector bundle, are isomorphic in the category of spaces with vector bundles?